# How to preview a selected image from a directory of images in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to display multiple images from a directory dynamically using PHP and JavaScript. So that I can display the selected image to give a enlarge view. I want something like using images as indicators and reference is https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp Please help !!!

```html
<div class="main">
  <?php
   $dirname = "images/";
   $images = glob($dirname."*");
   if($images){
  ?>
   <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4.5" direction="right" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
   <ul class="ulclass">
   <?php
    foreach($images as $image){ 
   ?>
   <div style="display:inline;" id="loadingImage">
   <?php echo '<img src="'.$image.'" onclick="show_image()" height="100" width="100" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;"">';?>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--Enlarge image-->
   function show_image(){ 
   alert("hello");
   var elem = document.createElement("img");
   elem.setAttribute("src","im");
   document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(elem);
   }
   </script>
   <?php }?>
  <?php }?>
   </ul>
   </marquee>
    <div id="imageDiv">
   <!-- Display the enlarged image here !! -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you be more specific about your problem? did you have any error? can you share the error in your question?

Comment: I have some images stored in a specific directory. From that directory I am displaying all the images in a marquee. And when i click on some image, the image should display separately.

Comment: That is exactly what this code does! I cannot get access to your directory for that reason I'm using some internet's images to load  the `marquee`, when you click on any image of the marquee, `show_image` enlarges the selected image and loads into `imageDiv`

Comment: You need to convey your problem in a better way. Do you expect everyone to read and understand your code?

Comment: I am still a beginner to programming language. Will do better next time.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is a simple example using JavaScript.

PHP will get the url of your images I think what you need is this JS code to show them

**Update**

I don't know the name of your php file but this is an example `test.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--Enlarge image-->
var imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv')

function show_image(image) {
  var newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute("src", image.getAttribute('src'));
  imageDiv.replaceChild(newImage, imageDiv.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <?php
        $dirname = "images/";
        $images = glob($dirname."*");
        if($images) {
    ?><marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4.5" direction="right" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
        <ul class="ulclass">
        <div style="display:inline;" id="loadingImage">
        <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" onclick="show_image(this)" height="100" width="100" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;">
        <?php } ?></div>
        </ul>
    </marquee>
    <div id="imageDiv">
      <!-- Display the enlarged image here !! -->
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?><div id="imageDiv">No images found.</div>
<?php } ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv')

function show_image(image) {
  var newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute("src", image.getAttribute('src'));
  imageDiv.replaceChild(newImage, imageDiv.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4.5" direction="right" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <ul class="ulclass">
      <div style="display:inline;" id="loadingImage">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/a2/8b/6e/a28b6ea6ad065de856b15dbabcce1adb.jpg" onclick="show_image(this)" height="100" width="100" style="cursor:pointer; display:inline; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px;">
        <img src="http://s12.favim.com/orig/160210/asian-girl-kfashion-korean-model-Favim.com-3977052.jpg" onclick="show_image(this)" height="100" width="100" style="cursor:pointer; display:inline; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px;">
      </div>
    </ul>
  </marquee>
  <div id="imageDiv">
    <!-- Display the enlarged image here !! -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code..When I click on the specific image, that image should display on the imageDiv tag.

Comment: That is exactly what this code does! Did you try using the `Run code snippet` button? When you click in an image, `show_image` enlarges the selected image and loads into `imageDiv`

Comment: Yes its working in run code snippet. With what extension should i save it? I want to run this in PHP.

Comment: I add an example of a `php` file. If the answer is correct please mark the question as answered please.

Comment: Yes.. Thank you its working in php.